# java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, file-io

I get this exception when I want to open a keystore

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \resources\keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Basically my application is like

```
src/
    client.java
    server.java
    resources/
        keystore
        truststore
```

And the faulty code :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/resources/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "redacted");
```

I also tried ./resources/keystore, resources/keystore, \\resources\\keystore etc..

My application is supposed to work in an executable jar so no absolute path technique please.

Comment: Can you post the code that tries to open the keystore?

Comment: You mean to establish the connection ? Because the keystore is supposed to be opened by this setProperty method.
I am sure there is no problem in the rest of the code because when I load the keystore with the VM argument -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=redacted everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the current directory path:

Java Code:

`String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();`

or this:

Java Code:

`String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Comment: He cannot use absolute paths. Else, you could simply do `this.getClass().getResource(".")` to get this class' absolute path as URL.

Comment: As I said I cannot use absolute path techniques as it will not work inside a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your resource in the CLASS_PATH, you can use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextclassLoader().getResource(keystore)
```

Comment: Actually I want people to launch it directly without doing anything. That's why I'm also doing the setProperty inside the code rather than giving VM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

About the different slashes: Use `File.separator` instead of `/`, then it should be in `"resources" + File.separator + "keystore"` (not tested).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work it prints the same thing.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \resources\keystore

Comment: What environment (IDE) are you using? Print out the absolute path produced by this relative one (something like new `File("resources/keystore").toString()`) and check in some file explorer where it points to. I think the problem might be that paths are created relative to the compiled `.class` file, not to the `.java` one.